# Click on HTML element using Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my element on HTML:

```
<a aria-role="button" href="" class="sc-button-play playButton sc-button sc-button-xlarge" tabindex="0" title="Play" draggable="true">Play</a>
```

I used Selenium to make the click event:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('playButton')
```

As you can guess, it doesn't work :)

Comment: Try it with xpath

Comment: I saw only that people use the id of the element, so I don't know how to use his class

Comment: Like @ThatBird said, try it with `xpath`. If you're not familiar with it, use the chrome add-in "xPath Finder".

Comment: I don't see any call to the click() method in your code.  Once you have buttons, what do you do with it?  Also, when you say it doesn't work, what error/exception message do you get.  This will give us a clue as to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with xpath -

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class = 'playButton']")
```

and to find `xpath` you need to do this -

- Right click on the element you want and click `inspect`
- Inspected element will be highlighted in chrome debugger. Right click on that element and bunch of options will open
- Click on `copy` and then click on `Copy XPath`

And use that xpath in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
# find all elements with following xPath (returns a list of elelements)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class = 'playButton']") # using xPath
```

or if you want to click on one element use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
# wait(at least 10 seconds) for element will be clickable and clcick on it
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class = 'playButton']"))).click();
```

[Here](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/web-elements-locating-mechanisms/locating-webelements-on-a-webpage/) you can find more inforamtion about locating elements.

Comment: isn't it case sensitive? playButton

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click a link, try

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Play").click()
```

If link text actually displayed on page as [PLAY](http://some.com) , try

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("PLAY").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are answers from @Andersson @AndreiSuvorkov and @ThatBird but seems there are still some more factors left for us to consider as follows:

As you are invoking `get(url)` and in the very next step trying to invoke `click()` on an element,

- Instead of `find_elements*` you need to use **`find_element*`** as follows:

  ```
  button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('class_name')
  ```
- Before you invoke click you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "element_xpath"))).click();
  ```
- When you desire to click on a particular element take help of a [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which will uniquely identify the *WebElement* within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). For `<a>` nodes (i.e. anchor tags) `LINK_TEXT` and `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` must be the preferred option. Apart from those a much conventional way would be to extensively use the `class` and `id` attribute (inabsence of `class` or `id` attributes fallback on other attributes) to construct an *CssSelector* or *XPath* as follows:
- `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Play"))).click()
  ```
- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.sc-button-play.playButton.sc-button.sc-button-xlarge[title='Play']"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='sc-button-play playButton sc-button sc-button-xlarge' and @title='Play'][contains(.,'Play')]"))).click();
  ```